# SMTPSendFailedException 590

Tags: java, email, smtp

Do you guys know what's the meaning of 590 exception?

```
com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 590 get price from sender failed
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a standard error. The smtp server you connected to made it up. But it doesn't matter per se - the relevant part is it's a 500 level error and hence immediately fatal (no retry)

I should elaborate: The 590 is an SMTP error code.